# Extract sequences from a FASTA file based on entries in a separate file

Tags: python, biopython

I have two files.

File 1: a FASTA file with gene sequences, formated like this example:

```
>PITG_00002 | Phytophthora infestans T30-4 conserved hypothetical protein (426 nt)
ATGCATCGCTCGGGTTCCGCACGGAAAGCCCAAGGTCTGGGATTACGGGGTGGTGGTCGG
TTACACTTGGAATAACCTCGCAAATTCAGAATCTCTACAGGCTACGTTCGCGGATGGAAC
>PITG_00003 | Phytophthora infestans T30-4 protein kinase (297 nt)
ATGACGGCTGGGGTCGGTACGCCCTACTGGATCGCACCGGAGATTCTTGAAGGCAAACGG
TACACTGAGCAAGCGGATATTTACTCGTTCGGAGTGGTTTTATCCGAGCTGGACACGTGC
AAGATGCCGTTCTCTGACGTCGTTACGGCAGAGGGAAAGAAACCCAAACCAGTTCAGATC
>PITG_00004 | Phytophthora infestans T30-4 protein kinase, putative (1969 nt)
ATGCGCGTGTCTGGTCTCCTTTCAATTCTTGCAGCCACTTTGACCACGGCCCAAGACTAC
```

File 2: A simple text file with JUST the accession identification of the gene. Like so.

```
PITG_00003
PITG_00005
PITG_00023
```

Every entry in File 2 is somewhere in File 1, but not every entry in File 1 is in File 2. I need to remove all the entries from File 1 that are not in File 2. I feel like there must be something in the biopython module that could help me, I just don't know what. For instance, I originally thought that I could extract just the accessions from my FASTA file using the `SeqIO.parse` function, but this really just lands me with two files of accession numbers. I don't know how to selectively extract the accessions that are in the other file. Maybe like reading all the entries from File 2 into a dictionary and then associated that entry with its matching entry in File 1 and use `SeqIO.parse` to extract the whole sequence...But I really don't know....Any help anyone could give me is extremely appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
f2 = open('accessionids.txt','r')
f1 = open('fasta.txt','r')
f3 = open('fasta_parsed.txt','w')

AI_DICT = {}
for line in f2:
    AI_DICT[line[:-1]] = 1

skip = 0
for line in f1:
    if line[0] == '>':
        _splitline = line.split('|')
        accessorIDWithArrow = _splitline[0]
        accessorID = accessorIDWithArrow[1:-1]
        # print accessorID
        if accessorID in AI_DICT:
            f3.write(line)
            skip = 0
        else:
            skip = 1
    else:
        if not skip:
            f3.write(line)

f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()
```

To briefly explain what's going on here... `accessionids.txt` is your **File 2**, whereas `fasta.txt` is your **File 1**. Obviously you'll need to replace these filenames with your actual filenames within the code.

First, we create a dictionary (sometimes referred to as a hash or associative array) and for every Accession ID in **File 2** we create an entry where the *key* is the Accession ID and the *value* is set to 1 (not that the value really matters in this case).

Next we look in **File 1** and again look at each line in that file. If the line in the file starts with `>` then we know that it contains an Accession ID. We take that line and split it along the `|` since every line with an Accession ID will have a `|` in the string. Next, take the first part of the split as specified by `_splitline[0]`. We use `accessorIDWithArrow[1:-1]` to chop off the first and last characters in the string which are the `>` symbol in the front and a blank space in the rear.

At this point, `accessorID` now contains the Accession ID in the format that we expect from **File 2**.

Next, we check if the dictionary we created and populated earlier has this Accession ID defined as a key. If it does, we immediately write the line with the Accession ID to a new file, `fasta_parsed.txt`, and set/reset the `skip` 'flag' variable to `0`. The `else` statement containing the `if not skip` segment will then allow subsequent lines associated with the Accession ID that we found to be printed to the `fasta_parsed.txt` file.

For Accession ID from **File 1** not found in the dictionary (not in **File 2**), we don't write the line to `fasta_parsed.txt` and we set the `skip` flag to 0. Thus, until another Accession ID is found in **File 1** that exists in **File 2**, all subsequent lines will be skipped.

Comment: thank you so much. I just realized that there were a lot of extraneous sequences in my file and it was messing up the program I'm running. You have been invaluable, especially with your explanation of the code.