# Extract sequences from a FASTA file to multiple files, file based on header_IDs in a separate file

Tags: python, regex, biopython, fasta

I am looking for a **python** solution to extract **multiple** sequences from a FASTA file into **multiple** files, based on a match to a list of header ID's in a separate file.

This is slightly more complex version of the problem posted on [Extract sequences from a FASTA file based on entries in a separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352219/extract-sequences-from-a-fasta-file-based-on-entries-in-a-separate-file) and https://www.biostars.org/p/2822/ which only output a single file for all matches.

#### I am new to python and am trying to find a way to:

- Take a file containing strings that will be in the fasta headers
- Have all records that match to a string, written to a separate fasta file

#### header_ID_strings file looks like this:

CAP357_2030_09WPI, CAP357_2040_11WPI, CAP357_2050_13WPI, etc...

#### a sample of my fasta file looks like this:

>CAP357_2030_009wpi_v1v3_1_056_00002_000.4
GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGG
>CAP357_2040_011wpi_v1v3_1_008_00006_001.1
GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT
>CAP357_2040_011wpi_v1v3_1_030_00002_000.4
GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT
>CAP357_2040_011wpi_v1v3_1_004_00001_000.2
GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT
>CAP357_2050_013wpi_v1v3_1_047_00002_000.4
GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT

#### expected output

file1: CAP357_2030_009wpi_v1v3.fasta
>CAP357_2030_009wpi_v1v3_1_056_00002_000.4
GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGG

file2: CAP357_2040_011wpi_v1v3.fasta
>CAP357_2040_011wpi_v1v3_1_008_00006_001.1
GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT
>CAP357_2040_011wpi_v1v3_1_030_00002_000.4
GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT
>CAP357_2040_011wpi_v1v3_1_004_00001_000.2
GTAAAATTAACCCCACTCTGTGTCACTCTAAATTGTACAACTGCAAAGGGT
etc...

This code is from the above link, but I want to have:
* matches written to separate outfiles
* I don't have to specify each outfile separately, if possible (I will have up to 30 outfiles)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from Bio import SeqIO

input_file = sys.argv[1]
id_file = sys.argv[2]
output_file = sys.argv[3]

wanted = set(line.rstrip("\n").split(None,1)[0] for line in open(id_file))
print "Found %i unique identifiers in %s" % (len(wanted), id_file)

index = SeqIO.index(input_file, "fasta")
records = (index[r] for r in wanted)
count = SeqIO.write(records, output_file, "fasta")
assert count == len(wanted)

print "Saved %i records from %s to %s" % (count, input_file, output_file)
```

So far this is what I have come up with (script below), but don't know how to get around manually specifying all the outfiles and variables (I have only included three here)

```
from Bio import SeqIO
import pandas as pd
import sys

input_file = sys.argv[1]
id_file = sys.argv[2]
output_file2020 = sys.argv[3]
output_file2030 = sys.argv[4]
output_file2040 = sys.argv[5]

colnames = ["2020", "2030", "2040"]
headerlist = pd.read_csv(id_file, names = colnames, header = None)
infile = list(SeqIO.parse(input_file, "fasta"))
2020_seq = tuple(headerlist.2020)
2030_seq = tuple(headerlist.2030)
2040_seq = tuple(headerlist.2040)

count2020 = 0
count2030 = 0
count2040 = 0
for record in infile:
    if record.id in 2020_seq:
        SeqIO.write([record], output_file2020, "fasta")
        countSU += 1
    elif record.id in PI_seq:
        SeqIO.write([record], output_file2030, "fasta")
        countPI += 1
    elif record.id in REC_seq:
        SeqIO.write([record], output_file2040, "fasta")
        countREC += 1
    else:
        print("no matches found")

print("number of SU is", count2020)
print("number of PI is", count2030)
print("number of REC is", count2040)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple brief suggestions:

If all your headers follow the same pattern, then you can extract the unique elements:

```
record.description.split("_")[1]
```

(yields "2040" from "CAP357_2040_011wpi_v1v3_1_008_00006_001.1")

If you use a dict you can assemble collections of records:

```
collected = {}
for record in records:
    descr = record.description.split("_")[1]
    try:
        collected[descr].append(record)
    except KeyError:
        collected[descr] = [record ,]
```

Then you can write out each collection to a new file:

```
file_name = "outfile%s" 
for (descr, records) in collected.items():   # iteritems in python2
    with open(os.path.join(file_path, file_name % descr), 'w') as f:
        SeqIO.write(records, f, 'fasta')
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!
I am getting a "No such file or directory" error, which I understand is something to do with opening a file that hasn't yet been created?
When I manually make an empty file "outfile4260" in the out directory (to test what's wrong), I get a "file is not open for writing" error.
Do I need to store the output as a variable before writing with SeqIO.write? Sorry if this is really obvious, this is my first python script.

Comment: PS: I have set file_path = os.getcwd()

Comment: Mistake in my code: the file handle should be of the form open(path/to/file, 'w') ('w' for 'write' -- would be 'r'  to read the file).  Try it with the 'w' (I have corrected the answer)

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, here is the 'final' script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# a script to extract fasta records from a fasta file to multiple separate fasta files based on a particular ID (time point) in a particular field, for a given delimiter
# to run, navigate to file location with command prompt and enter: python split_fasta_by_collections.py infile.fasta
from Bio import SeqIO
import os
import sys

records = SeqIO.parse(sys.argv[1], "fasta")
collected = {}
for record in records:
    descr = record.description.split("_")[1] # "_" sets the delimeter, "1" sets the field where counting starts at 0 for the first field
    try:
        collected[descr].append(record)
    except KeyError:
        collected[descr] = [record ,]

file_name = "outfile%s.fasta" 
file_path = os.getcwd() #sets the output file path to your current working directory

for (descr, records) in collected.items():  
    with open(os.path.join(file_path, file_name % descr), 'w') as f:
        SeqIO.write(records, f, 'fasta')
```